# Состоял ли он председателем?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Встретилось выражение "состоял председателем Ревизионной комиссии". У меня паранойя или все же нельзя "состоять председателем"? Скорее уж "быть председателем" или "состоять в должности председателя".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**СОСТОЯТЬ,**  3. Быть в составе, являться членом какой-л. группы, организации и т.п. С. в профсоюзе. С. в партии. С членом, пайщиком кооператива. // **Разг**. **Исполнять какие-л. обязанности, работать в качестве кого-л.** С. в денщиках. С. при командующем. **С. заведующим.** С. при посольстве.

В Нацкорпусе около 20 примеров на тему "состоял председателем", но они в основном относятся **к первой половине 20 века**, например:

Долгие годы **состоял председателем** сельсовета то у нас, в Олепине, то в соседнем селе Черкутине. [В. А. Солоухин. Капля росы (1959)]

Обыск закончился его арестом, а затем зашли ко мне и арестовали меня за то, что я **состоял председателем кадетской партии**. [В. П. Аничков. Екатеринбург – Владивосток (1917-1922) (1934)]

Скорее всего, **в современном языке это или устаревший, или разговорный вариант.**

Answer (score 1):

Да, неправильно это. Как минимум просторечие.
Это очевидное упрощение "состоял в должности председателя". "Состоять председателем", понятно, нельзя.

Сам оборот "состоять в должности" пришел из далеких времен начала советской власти и призван был заменить тяжелое наследие царского "служил". Хотя, объективности ради, и при царе-батюшке "состояли", но обычно "НА должности"  или "ПРИ должности" (кажется, разные должности требовали и разного  предлога, но за это уже не ручаюсь). Еще возможно было "состоять при полку, больнице, начальнике", это отдельный разговор.

"Состоять кем" - это уже уже какое-то недоразумение получается. Ну еще ладно бы слугой или денщиком... Но никак не председателем.

//==================

Безуспешно пыталась добиться от автора комментария вразумительных пояснений, придется ответить на то, как написано.

> Состоял в должности - это как раз не просторечие,

Допустим. Это много чего "НЕ". зачем об этом надо было сообщать?!

> а канцеляризм

Никаких причин для отнесения к канцеляризмам не вижу. Оборот (с учетом вариативности предлога) использовался в живой речи едва ли не чаще, чем в бюрократической.

> Потом всем говорил, что был там-то вице-директором, там помощником
>   управляющего, здесь состоял в такой-то должности, делал то-то… И. А.
>   Гончаров, «Май месяц в Петербурге», 1891

(Из вики-словаря), другие примеры лень искать.

И всё-таки. Надо же отличать оборот "состоял председателем" от "состоял в должности председателя". Первое - именно (или "как раз") **просторечие**.

Comment: Состоял в должности - это как раз не просторечие, а канцеляризм.

Comment: @user183861 Ну про канцеляризм можно поговорить, но почему "как раз"?!

Comment: IrinaGL, если можно, давайте лучше поговорим  с Вами о красивой и правильной речи, а не о канцелярских оборотах. Или о правильной неинтересно?

Comment: @user183861 Сначала хотелось бы уяснить смысл Вашей реплики. Если сейчас начинать говорить о чём-то ещё, можно сразу заказывать панихиду. До смерти не разберемся. Итак, почему вы вдруг решили уточнить что "состоял в должности" - не просторечие (про канцеляризм - потом) и что означает ваше "как раз"?

Comment: IrinaGL, извините ради бога, не хотела Вас обидеть ни в коем случае. Но я почему -то при употреблении таких длинных оборотов сразу вспоминаю профессора Преображенского с его знаменитой репликой "..так кто на ком стоял?"

Comment: @user183861, Не выдумывайте про обиды и ответьте, пожалуйста, на заданный вопрос. О Преображенском поговорим в другой раз. Или я буду считать Вашу реплику бессмысленной и не заслуживающей внимания. ***Почему вы вдруг решили уточнить, что "состоял в должности" - не просторечие (про канцеляризм - потом) и что означает ваше "как раз"?*** Кажется, это первый раз, когда я повторяю вопрос ***трижды***, против всех своих правил.

Comment: Просторечие  - слова, выражения, формы словообразования и словоизменения, черты произношения, не входящие в норму литературной речи, характеризующиеся оттенком упрощения, сниженности, грубоватости…Просторечие — слова, выражения, грамматические формы и конструкции, распространённые в нелитературной разговорной речи...  ; "состоял в должности председателя" таковым НЕ является! "Как раз" - это моя выделительная, уточняющая частица!

Comment: *"состоял в должности председателя" таковым НЕ является! "Как раз" - это моя выделительная, уточняющая частица!* - понятно. А теперь, если не трудно, вернитесь к моему ответу им прочитайте его еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Словарным рекомендациям это **не противоречит** (возможен как предложный падеж дополнения, так и творительный):

*Даль:*

> Находиться или быть. Состоять на службе, служить, или числиться.
>
> [пример с творительным падежом] Он состои́т мне должным.

*Толковый словарь русского языка Дмитриева. Д. В. Дмитриев. 2003:*

> 6. Если кто-либо состоит в чём-либо, то это означает, что этот человек
>
> участвует в деятельности, работе чего-либо.
>
> Состоять в профсоюзе, в партии. | Состоять членом какого-либо
>   общества,
>
> пайщиком кооператива.

На мой взгляд, *в современном употреблении* данный глагол всё-таки ограничен в своём грамматическом окружении (даже в значении "**числиться**" важнее не "**кем**", а "**где**") и требует дополнений в предложном падеже, поэтому "состоять председателем" (творительный падеж) **можно** лишь при наличии дополнительного контекста: с этим "состоять" должно быть согласовано *в предложном падеже* что-то ещё (*состоять где, в чём, при чём*), например:

> **состоять** председателем ревизионной комиссии **в/при облисполкоме**
>
> **состоять** председателем **в ревизионной комиссии**
>
> **состоять** парторгом **в партийной организации**